# Stop XCode from embedding build time in executables

Tags: xcode, xcode4, build-process, timestamp

XCode4 is putting build time in executables it creates. When I build the same code twice, binaries will differ by few bytes belonging to a unix timestmap.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

(I'm running expensive tests and benchmarks after each build and cache results based on hash of executables, but ever-changing executables broke my cache and pollute benchmark results with duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this by switching to building project myself "old skool" way with `Makefile`s & `gcc`.